# RethinkDb: Cannot call `changes` on an eager stream after .group()

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I need to show in a map **last data sent** by a bunch of sensors with unique `uid` and a typical `createdAt` date field, for this I need to craft a query like this **but with a live change feed over it**:

```
r.db("sensei")
  .table("sensor-data")
  .group("uid")  
  .max("createdAt")    
  .ungroup()('reduction')
  .changes()
```

This is throwing `Cannot call changes on an eager stream`

Any help would be appreciated!

I'm in a hurry!